# Loading file split input of hadoop map function into a data structure

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have designed a system where each map function is suppose to load its input (file split containing multiple CSV records) into a data structure and process them rather than processing line by line. There will be multiple Mapppers since I will be processing millions of records hence one mapper is totally inefficient.

I see from the example in WordCount, that the map function is reading line by line. Almost as of the map function is invoked for each line from the split it receives. I believe the input to this map should be the complete lines itself instead of sending it one line at a time.

Reduce function has other tasks at hand. So I guess, the map function could be tweaked to do the task its assigned. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

From what you explain I understand that your map input is not single line but some structure built from the several lines.
 In this case - you should create your own InputFormat which will convert the input stream (from the split) to the sequence of objects of YourDataStructure cluss. And Your mapper will accept these YourDataStructure objects. 

If the whole script is actually structure you want to process - I would suggest to do all the logic in mapper in one trick - you should know when there is last line in split. It can be done by inheriting TextInputFormat and tweak it to indicate you that there is last line. Then you build your structure in mapper, line by line, and when last line is indicated - do the job
.

Comment: Thx for your input. Instead of going over this, I thought of using 2 mapreduce jobs. The map function in each job is simply the Identitymapper with no processing done. The reducer in jobs has the actual functionality. So I planned to simple run them one after the other. I intend to make the reducers from the first job to directly send the input to the mappers of the second job without writing to disk. Can this be achieved ??

Comment: Followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369260/running-multiple-mapreduce-jobs-with-oozie